# What units does Finder use when listing an image's dimensions?

Tags: finder, graphics

What units does Finder use when listing an image's dimensions (e.g. 356 x 120 in the example below)?

[image: An image in Finder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely image dimensions on a screen are measured in `pixels`.

Open your image in Preview application and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>.